# Entity Framework Core Joining Related Table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an MVC app with Entity Framework Core. It doesn't work when I run it (I could have swore it worked before), but it works about half the time when debugging. What did I do wrong with setting up my Models and whatnot? I followed a little step by step guide, but now I can't find it. Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find the right search keywords to find something similar.

**Models/BaseProduct.cs**

```
public abstract class BaseProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Main Image")]

    public virtual FileDetails MainImage { get; set; }
    public virtual FileDetails AdditionalImages { get; set; }
    public virtual FileDetails Downloads { get; set; }

}
```

**Models/FileDetails.cs**

```
public class FileDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileDir { get; set; }
    public string FileText { get; set; }

}
```

**Controllers/CompressorController.cs**

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var list = await _context.Compressor.ToListAsync();
        foreach (var compressor in list)
        {
            if (compressor.MainImage == null)
            {
                FileDetails img = new FileDetails(){FileDir = "", FileName =  "NoImage.png", FileText = ""};
                compressor.MainImage = img;
            }
        }
        return View(list);
    }
```

So sometimes it does a join on the FileDetails table and sometimes it doesn't. The Compressor table (that inherits BaseProduct) has the IDs of the FileDetails table, so it seems like I didn't screw up too much.

**Solved:**

Issue appears to be with Rider. Ran code in Visual Studio and is consistently working with it.

Comment: I want to say that what you are thinking of Lazy Loading and that doesn't exist in the 2.0.1 version, expected in 2.1, the bits are actually in github, they recently posted about them

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how it applies join sometimes and sometimes not but I am pretty sure that EF Core current version doesn't support Lazy Loading. So, try eager loading;

```
var list = await _context.Compressor
    .Include(x => x.MainImage)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.AdditionalImages)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Downloads).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I did try something similar to this. I only did the first include and when I debug, I get the Error Unknown Identifier: list2. Also, when I do the ThenIncludes, it is looking at FileDetails, not Compressor.

Comment: "I get the Error Unknown Identifier: list2" what is that mean ? Would you provide some detail.

Comment: Yeah.. I don't get it either. But I added var list2 = await _context.Compressor.Include(x => x.MainImage).ToListAsync(); and that is the error Rider gives me when I try to debug and see what is returned. Maybe it is an issue with Rider, I will try that code with Visual Studio and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code similar to Rainman's suggestion, but that still wasn't working.

```
var list = await _context.Compressor
    .Include(x => x.MainImage)
    .Include(x => x.AdditionalImages)
    .Include(x => x.Downloads).ToListAsync();
```

I ran the code with Visual Studio instead of Rider and it seems to be working pretty consistently.